# How can I merge local .xib with server .xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

I use subversion of Xcode 4.5.

So I had some problem with xib file when i have wanted update it?

[image]

Question:

1. What does **C**(red) mean in left panel?
2. What does **?** mean in central panel?
3. Why don't I see some different code which is call problems?
4. How can I marge my local .xib with server .xib?
5. Maybe someone know better svn client?
6. or  someone know articles which describe how work with subversion in Xcode 4.5?

Comment: I believe you first should read and *understand* how subversion works *without* Xcode, i.e. on the command line. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ ; you can use `svn` in a terminal, and it is a quite good way to use it (I'm using it only on the terminal since 2008).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch And if possible, switch to some newer and more advanced version control system, e.g. git.

Comment: @Sulthan: I do agree about `git` but the OP specifically mentionned `svn`

Comment: @Sulthan: BTW, I'm using `svn` only for GCC related work, because sadly GCC is using `svn`; I was not able to easily use `git` with it (the main issue being merging GCC trunk into MELT branch, which I do with `svnmerge.py`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first both questions, I quote from [Apples documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/085-Save_and_Revert_Changes_to_Projects/manage_project_changes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH7-SW27):

```
  Badge - SCM status

  M       Locally modified
  U       Updated in repository
  A       Locally added
  D       Locally deleted
  I       Ignored
  R       Replaced in the repository
  –       The contents of the folder have mixed status; display the contents to see individual status
  ?       Not under source control
```

Regarding questions 3,4, and 6, the best you can probably do is to follow Basile Starynkevitch's advice.

Regarding question 5: XCode simply calls the svn command line tool. However, the version of svn that is shipped with XCode is usually not the newest one. Maybe you want to replace it by a more modern one. You will find other version, e.g. via [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).